# Replace part of the layout with already defined xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i am new to android development.
I want to replace part of my layout, i have a recycleview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarwrap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Current Orders"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview90"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="50">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/user_list_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_full_screen_black_24dp" />




            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fisnish"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/finishi" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to be replaced by another XML layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_item_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/gradient_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/billamount2"
                android:layout_width="406dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Bill Amount: "
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemcount2"
            android:layout_width="406dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:hint="Item Count: "
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="406dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:hint="Duration: 1 Hour"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distanceroad"
            android:layout_width="406dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:hint="Disatance: 70km"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distanceaddress"
            android:layout_width="406dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:hint="Delivery Address: 1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageclcik"

            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary2"
            android:elevation="40dp"
            android:padding="17dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ordernow" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried using this code that change the whole layout, its worked but i want to change part of the layout.
i am using this code into fragment

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.afterviewf, null);
                ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getView();
                rootView.removeAllViews();
              rootView.addView( v);
```

Any answer could help me 
Thanks.

Comment: You can hide/show the particular layout instead of inflate.

Comment: wrap part for changing into separated fragment and change it

Comment: How i can do it ?